# Issue in adding font to Application.Current.Resources after downloading font file at runtime in UWP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, uwp, uwp-xaml, webfonts

I have requirement of downloading font files at runtime and apply that Font to the text.
I successfully download the font file and added it to the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation  (Debug\AppX\Assets)`after added it to the `Application.Current.Resources` but the font not applying to the text but if I add manually font file to the Apps `Assets` instead of `(Debug\AppX\Assets)` folder then the font is getting applied successfully.
Here is complete code what I did

```
//Downloading font file
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://webfonts.sample.com/archivoblackregular/font.ttf");

//Creating font file in public space and writing all response to the file
StorageFolder PublicFontFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile fontfile = await PublicFontFolder.CreateFileAsync(fontFamily+".ttf",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(fontfile.Path, response);

//Moving that file to the Assets folder as we don't have direct access to create file in Assets folder
StorageFolder AssetsFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
await fontfile.MoveAsync(AssetsFolder, fontfile.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
StorageFile AssetsFontFile = await AssetsFontFolder.GetFileAsync(fontfile.Name);

//Adding that font file to application resources
Application.Current.Resources[fontFamily] = new FontFamily(AssetsFontFile.Path + "#" + fontFamily);
```

How can I complete my requirement?

Comment: why not try the local folder? There should be no limitation for loading resource for `Application.Current.Resources`

Comment: @Ax1le I tried this `Application.Current.Resources[fontFamily] = new FontFamily(AssetsFontFile.Path + "#" + fontFamily);` with local folder but it didn't work

Comment: I mean download in the local folder directly and try to get the resource. Will it work?

Comment: Is the file that you manually added to the assetet folder the same file you downloaded from your app?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT yes the same one

Comment: I've figured out what i was doing wrong, instead of doing this `Application.Current.Resources[fontFamily] = new FontFamily(AssetsFontFile.Path + "#" + fontFamily);` i had to do is if file is in local folder then `Application.Current.Resources[fontFamily] = new FontFamily("ms-appdata:///<folder>/<subfolder>/<file>" + "#" + fontFamily);`, if it is in assets folder then `Application.Current.Resources[fontFamily] = new FontFamily("ms-appx:///<subfolder>/<file>" + "#" + fontFamily);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what i was doing wrong, instead of doing this

`Application.Current.Resources[fontFamily] = new FontFamily(AssetsFontFile.Path + "#" + fontFamily);`

i had to do is if file is in local folder then `Application.Current.Resources[fontFamily] = new FontFamily("ms-appdata:///<folder>/<subfolder>/<file>" + "#" + fontFamily);`,

if it is in assets folder then `Application.Current.Resources[fontFamily] = new FontFamily("ms-appx:///<subfolder>/<file>" + "#" + fontFamily);`